How to merge tag resource
Does anyone know how to merge tags? I am working on code in Azure  that is used in multiple environments.
my main.tf file contains:
tags = {
  application     =  "Myapp"
  BU              =  "IT"
  DeploymentMode  = "terraform"
  Environment     =  "Production"
}

4 environments in all(Production, Staging, Development, Test)
terraform login
terraform workspace list

Production
Staging
Development
Test

I want to apply the changes to the Test workspace.
terraform workspace select Test 
terraform validate
terraform init

all work with no issues.
I then run terraform plan
Part of the code returned includes:
~tags    = {
  ~ Environment = "Test" -> "Production"}

I suspect this means changing the environment. Which isn't what I want. My research tells me I need to merge the tags. Not sure how to do this.

The shortest answer to this is to use terraform.workspace interpolation for the Environment tag, i.e:
tags = {
  application     =  "Myapp"
  BU              =  "IT"
  DeploymentMode  = "terraform"
  Environment     =  terraform.workspace
}

That should let you know then if you are in the wrong workspace.
